# What are the good options for doing Dependency Injection in Kohana/PHP?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, kohana

I see a few sparsely documented Kohana modules available for doing Dependency Injection. But I haven't found any good references to solidly point me in a direction.

Can anyone offer me a pointers/ideas/thoughts on the subject?

As we build out a service layer and improved unit testing in our app, we're interested in investigating what's possible for Dependency Injection in Kohana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kohana-Dependencies](https://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-dependencies), from [synapsestudios](https://github.com/synapsestudios), is a nice one.

But the thing is, if you are working with Kohana 3.2, you are gonna have to adapt the module, since it has support only to 3.1.x.

Kohana guys seem to not worry about things like PSR-0, dependency injection, etc. I don't know what's going on with that community.

Comment: They do care about PSR-0 and are currently working on it. See: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4001 and http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/10517/how-is-psr-0-support-for-kohana-3-3-going/p1

Comment: I don't think you followed the discussion on the forum (started by my), than.